# Maven Archetype With Custom File Structure

Tags: maven, maven-archetype, archetypes

I am trying to use Maven Archetypes to create a basic directory structure for a new project that is just a parent to several child projects. The structure inside `archetype-resources` looks like this:

```
root
|--- pom.xml
|--- subproject1
|    \--- foo.xml
|
\--- subproject2
     \--- bar.xml
```

Instead of generating this structure, I get the following error:

```
 Template 'subproject1/foo.xml' not in directory 'src/main/java'
```

Is there a way to tell Maven to not assume the archetype is generating a Maven Java project?